# How to differentially diagnose continuing sciatic pain given this existing information?

Tags: pain, muscle, nerves, differential-diagnosis, sciatic-nerve

Pains along the sciatic nerve apparently have numerous possible causes (18 of them [according to this article](https://veryhealthy.life/18-causes-sciatic-nerve-pain)).

Now, given the following facts, what would be appropriate differential-diagnostic measures/procedures/tests to determine the exact cause (or combination of causes) of such pains?

Relevant qualifying facts:

- Adult, but not elderly, male subject.
- Pain manifests only on one side of the body (the left side).
- Pain centered around the gluteal muscles (Piriformis?), occasionally shooting upwards or downwards.
- Pain intensity varies with time and posture; usually low intensity.
- Symptoms persist for over a year (but do not worsen).
- No relevant impact trauma.
- Regime of relevant physical exercise has little (and no lasting) effect.

Notes:

- I've tried to follow the guidelines in [this answer](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/are-differential-diagnosis-questions-on-topic) and keep this question on-topic; if you believe it isn't, please comment and help me edit it accordingly.
- If you believe the cause(s) are obvious based merely on the facts above, an explanation why that is would be a valid answer of course.

Comment: @JohnP: Oh yeah, you're right! I remember now that that's a thing. I even [remember the House episode now...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUDcX3NCcmY).

Comment: Just an off the wall question....how thick is the patients wallet and which pocket is it kept in?

Comment: @JohnP: Do you mean that in a metonymous sense, or in a literal sense? In both cases, not thick. And it is usually not kept in a pocket. And when it is, it's a front pocket and it alternates between right and left.

Comment: @einpoklum - Cool. Was just a random thought, I had a friend that had hip problems brought on by an overly thick wallet that was habitually in the same rear pocket.

Comment: @JohnP: More [TV inspiration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoPf98i8A0g) perhas? :-)

Comment: @einpoklum - No, actual person.

Comment: @Gordon: To put the link into perspective - it talks about patients with "sciatic neuritis of mechanical origin". How well does that fit with the condition described in the question?

Comment: @Gordon The question isn't asking for treatments; it's asking for a differential diagnosis. Please don't recommend treatments or post links to products.

Comment: @Carey Gregory Thanks I understand.

Answer (score 2):

**DIFFERENTIAL DIAGNOSIS**

Differential diagnosis in an adult man with a unilateral pain in the gluteal area lasting for over a year and not worsening, without a history of trauma, infection or inflammatory arthritis or other conditions (an incomplete list):

- **Degenerative disc disease (DDD)** with bulging or herniating disc(s) pressing upon the spinal nerve root(s) in the lower back ([lumbosacral radiculopathy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430837/))

  - Often runs in families; can be caused by acute or repetitive injury
  - Pain triggers: coughing, bending and certain other moves
  - Pain relievers: walking, lying down (not always)
  - Other common symptoms: tingling, numbness, leg weakness
  - In most cases heals/improves on its own in weeks/months
- **Hip conditions** with pain radiating to the gluteal area
- [**Piriformis syndrome**](https://familydoctor.org/condition/piriformis-syndrome/)

  - Caused by repetitive running, climbing stairs, sitting
  - Pain is typically worse during sitting ("sitting intolerance")
- [**Ischial bursitis**](https://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletter_article/By_the_way_doctor_What_can_I_do_about_ischial_bursitis)

  - Caused by prolonged sitting
  - Pain worse during sitting
- [**Sacroiliac joint dysfunction (sacroiliitis)**](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/sacroiliitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20350747)

  - Pain in the hip and buttock
  - Worse during prolonged standing or running
- [**Spinal tumor**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10959387)

  - Pain can persist during the night
- [**Postherpetic neuralgia**](http://www.cmaj.ca/content/182/11/E534) - inflammation of the nerve (neuritis) due to Herpes zoster infection

  - Typically (but not always) preceded by burning rash
  - Constant burning pain lasting for months/years

**DIAGNOSTIC PROCESS**

**1) History**

A doctor will likely ask detailed questions about the pain location, its triggers and relievers (coughing, sitting, walking, lying down).

**2) Physical examination (examples of tests)**

- [Straight leg raise (Lasegue) test](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5483767/): pain triggered by the leg raise speaks for a pinched nerve in the lower back (lumbosacral radiculopathy)
- [Provocative tests for piriformis (deep gluteal) syndrome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4718497/)

**3) Investigations**

- Blood tests to exclude inflammatory conditions (specific antibodies in ankylosing spondylitis and rheumatoid arthritis, sedimentation rate, C-reactive protein...)
- X-ray is often the first imaging investigation, which can detect broken vertebra, decreased space between vertebra (suggesting degenerative disc disease) and gross changes (spurs, deformities) due to inflammation
- CT or MRI of the lower spine or the hip is done when a problem with the discs or hip joint is suspected.
- There is no specific investigation for piriformis syndrome

NOTE: This is not a complete differential diagnosis of sciatica-like pain; it is a list of causes adjusted to the "case." The list of 18 causes linked from the question is grossly repetitive.

Comment: 1. Could an inflammatory condition really last a year without improving/worsening? 2. Can you be a bit more specific about which blood tests?  Also - thank you for the detailed and informative answer. Although I have more details, I will _not_ add them to the question.

Comment: Yes, OK, everything can be discussed here in the comments. Inflammation of the spine (ankylosing spondylitis) can last for several years, but I did not include any inflammation in my list because it's not really typical for the described case. I added few details about blood tests, but that part is not really important for the answer. My instict (because the pain is pretty constant) is that the cause is "mechanical" - something pressing on the nerve.